# org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Unexpected exception type thrown ==> expected

Tags: java, mockito

I am trying to test a method `sendEmail`. I would like to do a negative test on the method. I want to catch the `IllegalStateException` case. The `sendemail` method is in my ServiceClient class. In the test I am mocking `serviceClient` and `apiClient` the code for the method looks like this:

```
public HttpStatus sendEmail(){
        Supplier<HttpStatus> apiRequest = apiclient.post(command);
        return retry(apiRequest).orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException());
}

private <T> Optional<T> retry(Supplier<T> apiRequest) {
    T result = apiRequest.get();
    if (result != null) {
      return Optional.of(result);
    }
    result = apiRequest.get();
    if (result != null) {
      return Optional.of(result);
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

The test that I am trying to run looks like this

```
  @Test
  void sendEmailShouldThrowIllegalStateException() {

    when(apiclient.post(any())
        .thenReturn(null, null);
    
    assertThrows(IllegalStateException.class,
        () -> serviceClient
        .sendEndpointRegistrationEmail());
  }
```

I thought this would work because the mock method should return `null` which would trigger the exception, but it throws

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Unexpected exception type thrown ==> expected: <java.lang.IllegalStateException> but was: <java.lang.NullPointerException>
```

Just to clarify the issue isn't that I'm getting a NPE. The issue is that the wrong exception is being thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the reported exception, `NullPointerException` is quite natural.

Here down what is happening through your code:

- You instructed the `apiclient` mock to return `null` whenever the `#post` method is called
- Within your test fixture, you called `serviceClient#sendEndpointRegistrationEmail` with `serviceClient` (already having the `apiclient` mock injected I guess)
- When the above method is called, it will result in a call to `retry(Supplier<T> apiRequest)` with `apiRequest` argument being null (the result of your mocked call)
- `T result = apiRequest.get();` would then result in a `NPE` as `apiRequest` is null

The solution would then be to return a mock for any `apiclient.post(any())` call and configure the later to return `null` when `Supplier<HttpStatus>#get` is called:

```java
@Test
public void sendEmailShouldThrowIllegalStateException() {

  // create a Supplier mock for your request result
  Supplier apiRequestMock = Mockito.mock(Supplier.class);
  when(apiRequestMock.get()).thenReturn(null);

  // use the Supplier mock as return result
  when(apiclient.post(any())).thenReturn(apiRequestMock);

  assertThrows(IllegalStateException.class,
      () -> serviceClient
      .sendEndpointRegistrationEmail());
}
```

Comment: When I try that I get `Unexpected exception type thrown ==> expected: <java.lang.IllegalStateException> but was: <java.lang.ClassCastException>`

Comment: Could you provide the rest of the exception stacktrace? You should add your `sendEndpointRegistrationEmail` method sources as well.

Comment: org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Unexpected exception type thrown ==> expected: <java.lang.IllegalStateException> but was: <java.lang.ClassCastException>
 at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertThrows.assertThrows(AssertThrows.java:65)
 at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertThrows.assertThrows(AssertThrows.java:37)
 at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows(Assertions.java:2952)
        at org.service.api.ServiceClientTest.sendEmailShouldThrowIllegalStateException(ServiceClientTest.java:113)